# Compact-connectedness preserving functions

Tags: analysis

If $A$ and $B$ are subsets of the complex plane, compact and connected sets and if there is a bijection $f$ that maps $A$ onto $B$, is $f$ continuous?

Comment: Why would you expect $f$ to be continuous?

Comment: Let $A = B = [0,2]$ and $$f = \begin{cases} t+1, & t\in[0,1],\\t-1, & 2-t\in (1,2].\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 2):

No. A continuous bijection is automatically a homeomorphism on compact sets in the complex plane, but there are non-continuous bijections. Just take any bijection $f \colon A \to B$, and $a_1 \ne a_2 \in A$. Then $g \colon A \to B$ given by 
$$ g(a) = \begin{cases} f(a_2) & a = a_1\\ f(a_1) & a = a_2\\ f(a) & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases} $$
is a bijection. Note that one of $f$ and $g$ is non-continuous.